# Property with @Environment wrapper maintains old value in .onChange closure

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass?
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, world!")
      .onChange(of: verticalSizeClass) { newValue in
        print("verticalSizeClass:", verticalSizeClass!)
      }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why the `verticalSizeClass` property above maintains its old state in the `onChange` closure i.e in the portrait orientation the value is `compact` and `regular` in the landscape orientation? I would have assumed that the reverse should be the case.

PS: I know that I can get the correct state from `newValue` but I'm curious to know why the state isn't changing before the closure is invoked.

Comment: According to the documentation: _"The new value is passed into the closure. The previous value may be captured by the closure to compare it to the new value."_ So it seems that in the closure the old state is still in effect.

Comment: @tromgy I'm not using a closure capture to capture the old value. So `verticalSizeClass` should have the updated value. This is the expected behaviour with the property wrapper. But in this case, `verticalSizeClass` appears to not be updated.